# Sentencias SQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando mostrar datos de una base de datos, pero no me funciona

Tengo una parte del código de una sentencia SQL que es:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM titulos ORDER BY id DES LIMIT' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page;
```

Y quiero que aparezca en el archivo *PHP* la última publicación, pero no surte efecto, aparecen los datos por el `id` 1,2,3,4 y así consecutivamente..

He incluido la palabra clave `LIMIT` para limitar el número de visualizaciones por página.

Funciona todo bien, muestra los resultados y la páginación, pero en el orden id de menor a mayor.

Comment: Error de tipeo: `DESC`, no `DES`.

Comment: No surte efecto, he cambiado DES por DESC  y no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta sentencia

SELECT TOP 5  * FROM TABLE  ORDER BY column1 DESC;

Comment: Si perdonar ahora si funciona era por que había puesto DES en vez de DESC. Ahora funciona perfectamente. Gracias.

Comment: si la respuesta te ayudo , dale flechita arriba :)